# MATLAB: Using for loop to assign specific values in a vector to a new group/vector

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I am looking at neural network training data, and have a vector of 250 patients assigned evenly to 10 different groups, named `Icross`. This means that 25 patients have been assigned into group 1, 25 more into group 2, etc. `Icross` is a 250x1 vector.

I would like to create a for loop to split the patients into a testing and training group, `Itest` and `Itrain` vectors respectively. This means patients assigned into groups 1-5 are in `Itest`, 6-10 are in `Itrain`.

For my output, ideally there would be 250 rows of data in both vectors as output, composed of 1s and 0s indicating whether it's been assigned into the group or not, depending on which produced vector I look at.  However, using a for loop I've created just assigns one value of 5 into each vector. Any suggestions on how to modify my loop?

```
for Icross = 1:5;
    Itest = Icross;
    Itrain = ~Itest;
end
```

Ideal output:

```
Name    Value    
Itest = 250x1 logical
Itrain= 250x1 logical
```

My output from created for loop:

```
Name    Value
Icross  5 (1x1double)
Itest   5 (1x1double)
Itrain  0 (1x1logical)
```

Comment: Itest=randperm(repmat([0 1],1,125),250) is it ok for you? Itrain=~Itest. (I write from cell phone)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your loop assigns a new value to the same variable in each iteration. Just a numerical example, since I don't know how your underlying data looks like:

```
% A single vector containing all the patients...
patients = (1:250).';

% A 25-by-10 matrix representing the patients categorized into groups...
patients_grouped = reshape(patients,25,10);

% Two matrices, one for the training and one for the test:
test = reshape(patients_grouped(:,1:5),125,1);
train = reshape(patients_grouped(:,6:end),125,1);
```

Things become more complicated if you want to split your 250 patients into the 10 groups randomly. For this, the following code should do the trick:

```
% A single vector containing all the patients...
patients = (1:250).';

% Define the number of groups...
g = 10;

% Split the patients...
[n,m] = size(patients);
count = numel(patients) / g;
[~,idx] = sort(rand(n,1));
C = patients(idx,:);

patients_grouped = NaN(count,g);

for k = 1:g
    idx_k = ((k - 1) * count) + 1:(k * count);
    patients_grouped(:,k) = C(idx_k,:);
end
```

Once your patients have been randomly grouped into `10` categories, obtaining your logical arrays which defines if they belong to the test group or to the training group can be done like this:

```
patients_1to5 = patients_grouped(:,1:5);
patients_test = ismember(patients,patients_1to5(:));
patients_train = ~patients_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Icross` is a vector with values 1-10 assigning patients into the 10 groups, then

```
Itest = Icross <= 5;
```

is true (1) for all patients in groups 1-5, and

```
Itrain = ~Itest;
```

is true for all patients in the other groups (6-10).